# Rust Pig Latin exercise solution

Tags: rust, pig-latin

I just finished the chapter about collections from the Rust book, and it recommended trying some exercises provided there, such as a Pig Latin translator.

> Convert strings to pig latin. The first consonant of each word is moved to the end of the word and “ay” is added, so “first” becomes “irst-fay.” Words that start with a vowel have “hay” added to the end instead (“apple” becomes “apple-hay”). Keep in mind the details about UTF-8 encoding!

```
use std::io;
fn main() {
    let mut inp = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut inp).expect("Could not read");
    inp.remove(inp.len() - 1); // newline
    let cha = inp.chars().next().expect("Empty string");
    if is_consonant(cha) {
        inp += "-hay";
    } else {
        inp.remove(0);
        inp += &format!("-{}ay", cha);
    }
    println!("{}", inp);
}

fn is_consonant(c: char) -> bool {
    ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'].contains(&c)
}
```

Does my code satisfy whatever is required for it to be idiomatic Rust?

Comment: Can you provide the problem statement? It's easier to review code when having it available.

Comment: I don't believe you have satisfied the requirements of the exercise, since it says that you have to transform **each word**, and you have no word-splitting code in your implementation.

Comment: `is_consonant()` has a very misleading name - that sort of thing will certainly trip you up one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Suggested improvements:

Use `trim()` to remove the newline and other white spaces.

```rust
let mut inp = inp.trim().to_string();
```

---

The function `is_consonant()` actually checks if a letter is a vowel so it should be renamed.

---

The vowels can be extracted into a const.

```rust
const VOWELS: [char; 10] = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'];
```

---

The `is_vowel(c: char)` function can take reference to a `char` since that it what it uses.

```rust
fn is_vowel(c: &char) -> bool {
    VOWELS.contains(c)
}
```

Final Code:

```rust
use std::io;

const VOWELS: [char; 10] = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'];

fn main() {
    let mut inp = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut inp).expect("Could not read");
    let mut inp = inp.trim().to_string();

    let cha = inp.chars().next().expect("Empty string");

    if is_vowel(&cha) {
        inp += "-hay";
    } else {
        inp.remove(0);
        inp += &format!("-{}ay", cha);
    }

    println!("{}", inp);
}

fn is_vowel(c: &char) -> bool {
    VOWELS.contains(c)
}
```

---

## Additional changes:

It is possible to avoid some String allocations but doing so makes the code a bit more unreadable (in my opinion). Nonetheless I feel like it is worth at least mentioning them.

---

Replace `format!` by pushing to the original string to avoid a String allocation.

```rust
inp.remove(0);
inp += &format!("-{}ay", cha);
```

Can be replaced with:

```rust
inp.remove(0);
inp.push('-');
inp.push(cha);
inp.push_str("ay");
```

---

Avoid cloning the input String after trimming the whitespaces.

```rust
let mut inp = inp.trim().to_string();
```

Can be replaced with:

```rust
inp.truncate(inp.trim().len());
```

---

Convert the first character to lower case before checking if it is a vowel.

```rust
let cha = inp.chars().next().expect("Empty string");
```

Can be replaced with:

```rust
let cha = inp.chars().next().expect("Empty string").to_lowercase().next().unwrap();
```